# How do apps like "App Icons" change the app icons on springboard?

Tags: ios, springboard

How do apps like ["App Icons"](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id498956766) change the app icons on springboard?

Looks like it requires the user install a profile to customize the icons. Is some js executing with the profile? Would love to know how this actually works if anyone knows.

Comment: I doubt they're changing Springboard. Apple's exceedingly unlikely to approve that. This is probably just a launcher that uses apps' custom URL schemes to open common ones.

Comment: @ceejayoz I wouldn't post it if it wasn't on the app store. The link to the app is provided. The icons are changed whether it is in springboard or not is TBD.

Comment: The tags [iphone], [app-store], and [objc] have nothing to do with the subject of your question. Please do not add them again.

Comment: Take a look at the guidance in the [tag:objc] tag excerpt. Your question isn't about the language, and it doesn't contain any code. Therefore, the tag does not apply. The same general idea applies to _all_ tags here. The tags describe the subject of your question; they are not just for visibility. Your question is not specific to the iPhone hardware, and questions about the App Store are largely off-topic.

Comment: The reason you come here to ask questions is that it's a great place to get real answers. The reason that it is a great place to get real answers is that the members work hard to keep it organized and focused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't change the app icons. It adds URL-launching home screen icons that will open the actual apps, via their URL schemes, so typically you have a first page of these alias icons and the real ones are hidden in a folder somewhere. It's quite ridiculous, but strangely popular.

Apps that don't have a URL scheme can't have their icons "replaced" in this way.